# We got approved Vs. we got approval

Tags: american-english, british-english

I think the full sentence is "we got it approved" 
Please correct me if I'm wrong
and another question why approved (adj) comes after it (noun)?

Comment: Do you have example sentences?

Comment: We got approval to extradite him on Monday.

Comment: And it surprised both Boston and myself that we got it approved

Comment: Get it done/ have it done -> get it approved/ have it approved. It is like 'Please get it posted; Please have it signed.' It is quite different from the kind of sentences you wrote, "We got approval." Both 'we got it done and we had it done' are similar in tense. 'get something done' and 'have something done' follows the order verb + Pron + Adv.

Answer (score 1):

get is a stand-in for many other verbs, among them: **become, receive, buy (purchase), be**

- I got approval. I received approval.
- I got a letter today. I received a letter today.

get is also used instead of be:

- I got approved. = I was approved.
- I got fired. = I was fired.

**was/get approved** is not adjectival. It is a passive construction:

- I got approved [by x to do y]. For example.

  *get approved* is more colloquial and **be approved** is a bit more formal.

Comment: I remember a teacher once saying "Don't use 'get'. Get another verb." But then he was one of those strange Brits. I think everyone uses 'get' as a verb-of-all-trades to some degree or other (and doubtless generally more so in the States). "They're getting married" is 100% acceptable here in the UK whereas "I got approved" wouldn't be used by anywhere near that number, even in informal contexts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, get is a class/education thing, basically. And foreigners usually blow it as it is tricky to master.

Comment: We all sometimes blow English as tricky to master. And if we get remotely close, someone changes it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You make me feel tired.

Comment: Me too. That should have been 'We all sometimes blow English, tricky to master as it is.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth “Sillies, I went and saw the Queen. She says my hands are purfickly clean!”

Comment: No, I was correcting _my_ rhubarb. I can't get to see the Queen at the moment (though she's putting out some inspirational oratory for everyone in this battle). _Keep well_.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an adjective here, but a passive participle.

It's using the complex verb pattern "get *something* *verb*-ed", which is effectively a causitive passive:

> They got a house built.
>
> She got him promoted.

This seems to be a blend of the *get*-causitive (eg "I got him to tell me about it") and the *get*-passive (eg *I got promoted*).